# How to run functions in custom nested objects and arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I'm currently trying many ways to evaluate this in javascript:

```
var commands = [
  {
    func: "repeat",
    times: 3,
    actions: [
      {
        func: "func",
        callback: function() {
          console.log("one");
        },
      },
    ],
  }, {
    func: "func",
    callback: function() {
      console.log("two");
    },
  }, {
    func: "repeat",
    times: 2,
    actions: [
      {
        func: "func",
        callback: function() {
          console.log("three");
        },
      }, {
        func: "repeat",
        times: 3,
        actions: [
          {
            func: "func",
            callback: function() {
              console.log("four");
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }, 
];
```

But I'm still stuck at the part that have nested repeat commands, and the result I expected to parse from top to bottom of this commands array.

How to evaluate this array? And are there any good resource related to this?

(Assume every value in array must be object and having at least a key "func")

Edit: expected result http://pastebin.com/Chd6DLdB

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: try making an object with keys of 'func' and values of 'callback' ; but keys need to be unique, like there can be only one object with => {func: "func",callback:fn(){...}}

Comment: var obj={};$.each(commands,function(i,c){obj[c.func]=c}) run this in an iterative function to create that object

Comment: the expected result maybe too long to post it here

Answer (score 0):

You can have a recursive function that will loop over and search for `actions` and `callbacks` and process then.

```js
function callCommands(obj) {
  // Check if received object is an array. If yes, loop over them
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    obj.forEach(callCommands)
  } 
  // If received object is not an array, check if it has a property `callback`. If yes, call it.
  // Also check if it has `actions`. If yes, loop over and process them as well
  else if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('callback')) {
      obj['callback']();
    }
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('actions'))
      callCommands(obj['actions'])
  }
}
```

```js
var commands = [{
  func: "repeat",
  times: 3,
  actions: [{
    func: "func",
    callback: function() {
      console.log("one");
    },
  }, ],
}, {
  func: "func",
  callback: function() {
    console.log("two");
  },
}, {
  func: "repeat",
  times: 2,
  actions: [{
    func: "func",
    callback: function() {
      console.log("three");
    },
  }, {
    func: "repeat",
    times: 3,
    actions: [{
      func: "func",
      callback: function() {
        console.log("four");
      },
    }, ],
  }, ],
}, ];

function callCommands(obj) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    obj.forEach(callCommands)
  } else if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('callback')) {
      obj['callback']();
    }
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('actions'))
      callCommands(obj['actions'])
  }
}

callCommands(commands)
```